# How to disable live window resizing in Trusty Tahr

Tags: unity, 14.04, gui

Subject says it all. How do I get rid of live window resizing? There's no setting for that either in "Appearance" or in "Unity Tweak Tool".

Comment: This should still be valid: http://askubuntu.com/questions/291386/how-do-i-enable-live-window-resizing-in-ubuntu-13-04 (though the q askes about activating it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to install CCSM: `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`.

Launch it with `ccsm` and go to `Window Management` and click `Resize Window`.

Select `General` tab and change `Default resizing mode` from `Normal` to `Rectangle`.

[image]

Sorry for the display language but it won't run with `export LANG=en_US`.